# Linq where condition on a collection (navigation property)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, collections, where-clause

I have been sifting through several posts but none of the answers seems to work or to be applicable in my case, maybe I am overseeing something ...

I have an Entity Yogi which have a Collection of Subscriptions (also an Entity).
I want to retrieve a Yogi but including only the Subscriptions after a specific date.

**I tried the following (also replaced the (2nd) Where with a Select):**

```
ctx.Yogis.Where(y => y.YogiId == id)
         .Include(y => y.Subscriptions.Where(s=> s.YogaClassDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date))
         .Include("Subscriptions.YogaClass")
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

**but received this error as an result:**

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. 
>   Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I want to avoid if possible to have to iterate and compare afterwards so is there any way of getting this directly or as others have suggested, no there isn't and I should get a collection of all Subscriptions for that Yogi and filter out the ones I don't want to show?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or directions!

**EDIT (THANK YOU GERT ARNOLD):**
I tried the anonymous projection but I missed a crucial part

```
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => x.b)
```

**So this made it work:**

```
ctx.Yogis.Where(y => y.YogiId == id)
         .Select(y => new
                      {
                       y,
                       Subscriptions = y.Subscriptions.Where(s=> s.YogaClassDate >= DateTime.Now)
                      })
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x => x.y)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Filtered `Include` isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
    ctx.Yogis.Where(y => y.YogiId == id)
     .Include(y => y.Subscriptions)
     .Include("Subscriptions.YogaClass").Where(s=> s.Subscriptions.YogaClassDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Subscriptions is a Collection so I can't do the .YogaClassDate ...

Comment: This is wrong anyway. It still includes *all* YogaClasses of each yogi. `Include` can't be filtered, period.

Comment: @GertArnold, what about Anonymous projection?

Comment: @GertArnold where method not filter it?

Comment: No, that only filters the yogis not their classes.